# need to decrease the run time of my program

Tags: python, string

I had a question where I had to find contiguous substrings of a string, and the condition was the first and last letters of the substring had to be same. I tried doing it, but the runtime exceed the time-limit for the question for several test cases. I tried using map for a for loop, but I have no idea what to do for the nested for loop. Can anyone please help me to decrease the runtime of this program?

```
n = int(raw_input())
string = str(raw_input())
def get_substrings(string):
  length = len(string)
  list = []
  for i in range(length):
    for j in range(i,length):
      list.append(string[i:j + 1]) 
  return list
substrings = get_substrings(string)
contiguous = filter(lambda x: (x[0] == x[len(x) - 1]), substrings)
print len(contiguous)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly the question, please let me know if thats not the case but try this:

Not sure if this will speed up runtime, but i believe this algorithm may for longer strings especially (eliminates nested loop). Iterate through the string once, storing the index (position) of each character in a data structure with constant time lookup (hashmap, or an array if setup properly). When finished you should have a datastructure storing all the different locations of every character. Using this you can easily retrieve the substrings.

Example:

codingisfun

take the letter i for example, after doing what i said above, you look it up in the hashmap and see that it occurs at index 3 and 6. Meaning you can do something like substring(3, 6) to get it.

not the best code, but it seems reasonable for a starting point...you may be able to eliminate a loop with some creative thinking:

```
import string
import itertools

my_string = 'helloilovetocode'

mappings = dict()

for index, char in enumerate(my_string):
    if not mappings.has_key(char):
        mappings[char] = list()

    mappings[char].append(index)
    print char

for char in mappings:
    if len(mappings[char]) > 1:
        for subset in itertools.combinations(mappings[char], 2):
            print my_string[subset[0]:(subset[1]+1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please provide an example? i am new to python and exactly understand hashmaps.

Comment: How about the single alphabets in the string? aren't they substrings too? can this method be utilised to print the single alphabets, i.e. the substrings as well?

Comment: thats a simple modification, in the first for loop print each character after adding them to the dictionary mappings

Comment: I checked the timings for this method. it took more time than my code(about 0.2 seconds more). Thank you for your method, though. it works and i like it! Would be glad if there are any more methods to reduce the runtime.

Comment: removed the first for loop, was unnecessary. There is a nested for loop at the end that can be eliminated if you find a better way to get all combinations of the indices in the final array. A recursive solution may be good for this problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code far too inefficient in terms of algorithmic complexity.

Here's an alternative (a cleaner but slightly slower version of soliman's I believe)

```
import collections
def index_str(s):
    """
    returns the indices characters show up at
    """
    indices = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        indices[char].append(index)
    return indices

def get_substrings(s):
    indices = index_str(s)
    for key, index_lst in indices.items():
        num_indices = len(index_lst)
        for i in range(num_indices):
            for j in range(i, num_indices):
                yield s[index_lst[i]: index_lst[j] + 1]
```

The algorithmic problem with your solution is that you blindly check each possible substring, when you can easily determine what actual pairs are in a single, linear time pass. If you only want the count, that can be determined easily in O(MN) time, for a string of length N and M unique characters (given the number of occurrences of a char, you can mathematically figure out how many substrings there are). Of course, in the worst case (all chars are the same), your code will have the same complexity as ours, but the in average case complexity yours is much worse since you have a nested for loop (n^2 time)